# Setup to not automatically open/close folds when writing fold-markers (in the presence of a modeline)

Tags: folding

Say I have a file:

```
// vim: syntax=rust fdm=syntax
{
  blah blah
}
```

Let's say that lines 2 through 4 are folded:

```
// vim: syntax=rust fdm=syntax
+ { ... }
```

Now I am in insert mode. I insert a newline on line 2, and begin typing `{`, then `}`.

I type `{`, and the folded block updates to being a deeper nesting:

```
// vim: syntax=rust fdm=syntax
{
+- { ... }
```

Then I type `}`, and the previously folded block recognizes it's gone up a nesting level, and opens:

```
// vim: syntax=rust fdm=syntax
{}
{
  blah
}
```

The behavior is also inconsistent with blocks that follow later in the file, wherein typing `{` opens them.

This occurs whether I'm using `fdm=syntax` or `fdm=marker fmr={,}`

**How do I stop previously unfolded/folded blocks from closing/opening every time I write fold-markers earlier in the file?**

I've been using the `setlocal` trick in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * if !exists('w:last_fdm') | let w:last_fdm=&foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave * if exists('w:last_fdm') | let &l:foldmethod=w:last_fdm | unlet w:last_fdm | endif
```

And it works great for files that don't have modelines setting the syntax and the fold method. For some strange reason it doesn't work when I have the modeline as described above.

Comment: I frequently use folds for navigating, but disable them when editing, as an example of an alternate workflow. One could set up `InsertEnter/Leave` autocmds to trigger e.g. `zi` and the like. (I too find this behavior annoying, and avoid it altogether—hoping for a solution.)